# jquery - read more, show/hide html content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to implement a simple read more feature in jquery where i can cut off some content and then show/hide the remainder using a button.

If it were a simple block of text i could simply wrap the remainder in a span, but the content can be html.

For example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea --CUT OFF HERE-- commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in</p>
<p> voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

In this example i would like to cut off at the marker --CUT OFF HERE-- which in the middle of the first p.  But, it might not be inside a p, or there may be no html also.  I just need to cater for it should it be there

How can this be achieved?

Comment: It might be best, I think, if you somehow forbid `--CUT OFF HERE--` from appearing inside of an HTML element.

Comment: Yes, this is just to illustrate the cut off point in the question

Comment: Expand and Collapse HTML content: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-expander

Comment: You should really consider splitting up the content less/more without js. It will look much more pretty if you do it serverside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/65u5R/

Here's a somewhat complicated solution. The upshot is that you're using `.html()` to append the first half of the content to an HTML element, and letting jQuery close it for you. Then when the "read more" link is clicked, `.html()` is used again to fill the HTML element with the entire string, minus the "--CUT OFF HERE--" segment.

```
var allstr = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea --CUT OFF HERE-- commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in</p><p> voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
    $container = $('#container'),
    splitstr = "--CUT OFF HERE--",
    arr_str = allstr.split(splitstr),
    fstr = (arr_str[0] === allstr) ? allstr : arr_str[0]+"...",
    readmore = "<a href='#'>Read more</a>";

$container.html(fstr);

$(readmore).on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().html(arr_str.join(''));
}).appendTo($container);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is really what you are looking for. Take a look at the code below:

```
<p>Click the button to show or hide the content below <input id="button" type="button" value="Read More" /> </p> 

<p id="show_hide" style="display:none;">This content will show and hide on click</p>
```

(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#show_hide').toggle(300);
    })

})(jQuery);

There's nothing special here really. I initially hid the 'show/hide' paragraph that is supposed to be displayed when a user clicks on the button. The inline CSS was only done for the purpose of this question. Otherwise, experts recommend that you write your CSS on an external file... I then used the **toggle()** function in the **click** event handler to make the animation happen...

see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wuGbh/

Answer (score -1):

First thing first, You shouldn't display text in html without wrapping it with in any html tag. There are various way to wrap ur text with any html tag, div,p,span etc. So here is my assumption ur text wrapper is div or any tag with classname response_text.

```
<div class="response_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea --CUT OFF HERE-- commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in</div>

.show_me {
  display:none;
}

function makeToggle(ele){
  var html = $("." + ele).html();
  var textarray = html.split("--CUT OFF HERE--");
  var p = $("<p />").text(html).addClass("hide_me");
  var p1 = $("<p />").text(textarray[0]).addClass("show_me");
  var brn = $("<button />").click(function(){
    $(".hide_me").hide();
    $(".show_me").show();
  }).text("hide me").addClass("hide_me");
  var brn1 = $("<button />").click(function(){
    $(".show_me").hide();
    $(".hide_me").show();
  }).text("show more").addClass("show_me");
  $("." + ele).html("").append(p).append(p1).append(brn).append(brn1);
}
makeToggle("response_text");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NNMh3/16/